# What's the best way to find the home directory of an arbitrary user in Java?

Tags: java

What's the best way to find the home directory of an arbitrary user (not necessarily the one running the program) on a Unix-like system, given their username?

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
public void writeToHomeDirectory(String user){
    File homeFolder = new File("~" + user);

    File f = new File(homeFolder, "A File");
    //f.writeStuff()
}
```

This doesn't work as the '~user' doesn't expand as this is a shell feature. Is there any way to do this in Java, or is the only way going to involve running a shell with Runtime.exec()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to self-answer, but I had a lot of faffing trying to get the command in particular just right, so I'll put this here in case someone else happens to have exactly the same problem as me.

```
private File getHomeDirectoryOf(String username) throws IOException, Exception{
    String[] command = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "echo ~"+username + ""};
    Process echo = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(echo.getInputStream()));

    try{
        echo.waitFor();
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e){

    }

    String path = br.readLine();
    echo.destroy();

    if(path.contains("~")){
        System.out.println("Home directory for " + username + " cannot be found.");
        throw new Exception();
    }
    else{
        return new File(path);
    }
}
```

This was only necessary for my particular problem - if you need only local users or only LDAP users, the other answers give far better ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this in Java.  But you could do it by reading the "/etc/passwd" file, looking for the entry for `user` and extracting the user's home directory.  That's basically what the shell does ...

Comment: Yes this seems like a good solution. Can't we list sub-directories in /home/ directory & find out home directories of all users?

Comment: What if users aren't stored in /home/? They're not on our corporate network. What about Windows?

Comment: I like this answer, but I'm afraid it won't work for my purposes - we need to include network (LDAP) users, which aren't listed in /etc/passwd. I'm leaning more and more towards using a shell command like "echo ~user" or "finger user".

Comment: Perhaps you could query LDAP instead?  Certainly there are LDAP libraries available for Java.

Comment: Can't guarantee that the user will be an LDAP user - only that they *might* be LDAP. Also want to avoid the user having to put LDAP settings into the application if they don't have to.

Comment: With those additional constraints, launching an external shell seems like the best option.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that the information about all the users in the system will be hard to get without the right privileges.

Since it's operating system dependent, you could use the property `user.home` and then substitute the username, from the property `user.name` with the user String that you've passed into the method:

```
    String user = "..."; // found elsewhere
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    String newUserHome = home.replace(System.getProperty("user.name"), user);
```

This at least keeps the convention of the current OS's place for user home directories, which might have been customised. If the user home directories are not in a consistent location (and I can't imagine that's ever the case), then all bets are off IMO.

Comment: If you have LDAP network users, you can put their home directories on any NFS share you want, so they may well not be in the same folder. Nice lateral thinking, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can exec 'sh' to have it evaluate the ~. but it's a strange requirement. Odds are you won't have write access to it anyway, maybe not even read access.